# Grails Gorm MongoDB index Embedded String Map

Tags: grails, mongodb, groovy, grails-orm

I wanted to make some translatable content with rest service so i decided to create collection with this structure. But I can't find BSON by value from String Map. 
    class LocalizableString{

```
   static mapWith = "mongo"
   ObjectId id
   Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

Then i wanted to get like this. But it works like join query.

```
def list = LocalizableString.createCriteria().list {
        values{ like('value',"%${value}%") }
    }
```

Here is similar plain mongo example. But how can i implement it with gorm mongoDB http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Example

Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class BaseService {

    def findByLocalizableString(def domainClass ,def query , def field ,def params = null) {

       def q = new BasicDBObject()
       def queryList = []
       def allowedLanguages = ConfigurationHolder.config.grails.localizableString.allowedLanguages
       allowedLanguages.each { locale ->
          queryList.add(new BasicDBObject("values.${locale}", new BasicDBObject('$regex', /.*${query}.*/)))
    }
       q.put('$or',queryList)
       def lsc = LocalizableString.collection.find(q)

       def list = lsc.hasNext() ? domainClass.createCriteria().list(params) {
          or {
              while (lsc.hasNext()) {
                  def n = lsc.next()
                  eq("${field}",n._id)
              }
          }
       } : null
       return list
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this, but I'm fairly certain the Mongo GORM plugin does *not* work with criteria relation traversal, which is what this *looks like* (despite not really being like that).

From mongoGorm website (http://blog.mongodb.org/post/18510469058/grails-in-the-land-of-mongodb):

> Some of the GORM features that are not supported include:
>
> Criteria queries on associations
>
> HQL
>
> Groovy SQL

So you may need to rethink the Map structure you have as a data model here :/ Anyone more experienced can weigh in?

Comment: Tnx but i used mongo low lvl api on that